# How to get max speed permitted against a particular latitude and longitude

Tags: here-api

I need to get the max speed limit of a street. I will have latitude and longitude and I am interested only in getting max speed.

Looking into rest api calls the following seems to be best suited to me but it seems it's now a legacy code:

https://legacy.route.cit.api.here.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.json

Can you please help me in getting the best rest api call for my case.

Country: USA
State: CA

Comment: What sort of spatial scale are you looking for? Globally? All of Africa? Munich? I suggest you're a little more specific at least as far as administrative units are concerned.

Comment: I am sorry for missing details. For now it is California, USA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the new router with getLinkInfo here: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-get-link-info.html or use the Platform Data Extension (https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/platform-data/topics/overview.html)